# CKEDITOR - Open paste as plain text window by default

Tags: ckeditor

I am looking for a way to ensure that I always get plain text if the user pastes text using ctrl+v.

I have tried adding config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true; to my CKEDITOR.editorConfig function and I still get a large amount of nbsp; etc. 
The only way I seem to be able to get true plain text is using the paste as plain text button on the toolbar. 
Is there a way to open that window if the user uses ctrl+v to paste and have them paste there.
I know it could be done with fckeditor, but have not been able to figure out how to make it work in ckeditor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the latest SVN version (should differ a lot from 3.6.3) and when I set `forcePasteAsPlainText : true` (note - you have to do this before initializing editor or in `editor.replace( el, config )` - doing this later won't work.

I'm pasting (by ctrl+v) copied part of a website and text is being pasted correctly. No styling, no superfluous and non-plain-text elements.

However, the `&nbsp;` entities are fully correct in plain text - they replace multiple spaces and you'll have the same result for content pasted by pastetext dialog.

If you still want to open pastetext dialog on ctrl+v you can use `CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes`. There're couple of defaults in this array, so you shouldn't override them, but you can add your own keystroke (before initializing editor):

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes.push(
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 86, 'pastetext' ]
);
```

If you want to add this keystroke only for one editor (because editing global config affects all) then you'll have to use custom config file (see http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations#Using_the_config.js_File) and add your keystroke this way:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.keystrokes = [
        // copy here all keystrokes from _source/plugins/keystrokes/plugin.js
        [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 86, 'pastetext' ]
    ];
};
```

This way OFC isn't convenient, but this will be fixed in the next major release of CKEditor.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was trying to do, and worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This would paste as plain text even from MS Word

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.YourInputControlName;
editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.setData($('<div/>').html(evt.data.dataValue).text());
}, editor.element.$);
```